# Prevent Svelte from adding random classes

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a `shadow-root` component and I simply don't want svelte-kit to add those random classes to that specific element or its child elements. It would be nice if there was something in the settings like: `document.getElementById("<id>").cssHash == false`

Or any possible hacks to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Those classes are how Svelte can add CSS that is scoped to that specific component. It adds that class to each selector in a component's `<style>` block.

Comment: I know that @M.Desjardins Sveltes uses this for scoped CSS but what I want is to disable it on that certain element only. Or any hacks if that's not something possible in svelte

Comment: @AbhaySalvi you can, but you need to create a global module css file and import that file and use it like this https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-modules or write inline css code. and to select the same element you can use `bind:this`. unfortunately I don't know another way simple than this. hope it helps

Comment: What is the point?

Comment: @H.B. I'm politely asking if it's possible or not. If not then I'll figure out some other ways to achieve it

Comment: You did not answer my question. What you are trying to do is probably *highly misguided*, so you should provide a reason for why are doing this.

Comment: Okay @H.B. I'm building a mini page builder, and using iframe was a pain so I'm trying if using a shadow root would make things easier. Now I want the user to be able to add their own classes but svelte is touching the shadow-root component which is meant only for the user. Thank you!

Comment: Still don't see this as a valid goal. Adding classes should not conflict in any way with the existing Svelte classes. I just cannot recommend this. If the internal Svelte implementation changes things might break, too.

Comment: Okay, thank you @H.B. I cannot afford breaking svelte for some feature. I'll now just move on and find something else. Really thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `use` action ([tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions) | [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action)) for this:

```js
let noClass = node => {
    node.classList.forEach(e => {if (e.startsWith('svelte-')) node.classList.remove(e)})
}
```

Then you use the directive on elements:

```html
<div use:noClass>
```

et voila! Full example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/31b4e0e04ec84ac6995f2a5f5c1f9cd5?version=3.57.0

Comment: Note: The Svelte REPL uses `svelte-` as a prefix, but your app seems to use `s-`, so you need to adjust the code, but it should still work.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only hack it seems for me to work. Thanks!